# Android Application files similar to .cod and .jad file in Blackberry

Tags: java, android, eclipse, blackberry

I have a Blackberry application which contains `.jad`, `.cod` files and the velocity file `.vm` get automatically created. Now I want to use same application with Android. So which files are needed?
I am currently using Simulator 2.2 on Windows XP.

Again I am facing one problem that the browser URL size is too small. So I am using Bitly to shorten the URL. Again I can not copy and Paste the URL?

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

A J2ME BlackBerry application has nothing to do with an Android Java application. You have to start from scratch using Android SDK and re-write the application.

BTW: Please ask only one question at a time.